# Unable to load a XAML resource from a project subfolder at design-time

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, resources, design-time

I defined a fake view model to be used by a view in a WPF application at design time (Visual Studio 2012, .NET 4.5). The view model references an image that is a part of the project content. As long as I put the image in the root project folder, it is successfully loaded at design-time using the following URI convention:

```
var Image = new BitmapImage(
new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/MyAppAssemblyName;component/MyImage.png"));
```

The image is marked as embedded resource (I actually tried to mark it as content and it also loaded fine).

But I want to use it from the Sample project subfolder, so I changed the code above like this:

```
var Image = new BitmapImage(
new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/MyAppAssemblyName;component/Samples/MyImage.png"));
```

Then it stops working. Whatever I try (content, embedded resource etc.), nothing is loaded from the project's Samples subfolder. This is very strange since I see various examples of using subfolders, although I haven't found examples for design-time. I also tried to use pack scheme siteoforigin, but then Designer tries to load images from Visual Studio application folder.

I saw a similar problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493106/wpf-c-sharp-unable-to-find-subfolder-image-resource)

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it work if you set the image's Source in XAML?

Comment: Yes, I can specify both "MyImage.png" and "Samples/MyImage.png", and they both work from XAML. The problem is only to load images from subfolder programmatically.

Comment: I don't have VS2012 at work, but I just ran a quick test and using the d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=lcl:DesignData}" syntax worked just fine in VS2010. Note that my images' build action is Resource. I'll check 2012 when I get home in a couple hours. One thing you can try is attaching a new instance of VS as a debugger to the one that is running the designer. You might be able to see some errors in the output window.

Comment: Thank you Abe, but did you programmatically refer to images in the design data model?

Comment: Yes. I created a property called Image that I set to a .png in the data model's constructor. It worked fine for an image I had in a subfolder.

Comment: I believe I am getting it. If I convert folder name to lower case and keep the original case of the filename, then it works!

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd finally got it, and the problem lied in character casing. Here's my project structure:

MyProject
    - Samples
        - MyImage.png

The following URI works:

```
pack://application:,,,/MyProject;component/samples/MyImage.png
```

These don't:

```
pack://application:,,,/MyProject;component/Samples/MyImage.png
pack://application:,,,/MyProject;component/samples/myimage.png
```

**UPDATE**. After and advice from a Microsoft forum I did more tests restarting Visual Studio after each URI change, and my theory above appears to be wrong. Character casing doesn't matter (all three versions worked), but sometimes VS Designer does not catch up most recent change and VS restart is needed in order for the last change to be used by the Designer.